# iOS- Using Nuance Speechkit, error: Ambiguous use of recognize(withType:detection:language:delegate:)

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition

I am trying to use Nuance Speechkit and build a speech recognition app that can produce transcribe for speech. The method for recognizing speech in Nuance is giving error: Ambiguous use of recognize(withType:detection:language:delegate:) while calling the method:

skTransaction = skSession?.recognize(withType: SKTransactionSpeechTypeTV, detection: SKTransactionEndOfSpeechDetection.none, language: LANGUAGE, delegate: self)

My guess is I am doing it in Swift 3, maybe, Nuance is having trouble with the new syntax, or Swift 3 compiler is causing some internal issue, because same method works fine in Swift 2.3.

Please help, if anyone have any idea about such bug.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, i resolved it using alternative method with empty options parameter

```
let options = [
        "" : ""
    ]

    _ = session?.recognize(withType: SKTransactionSpeechTypeDictation, detection: .long, language: "eng-USA", options: options, delegate: self)
```